# POST request to Envelopes:create method

Tags: docusignapi

First of all - all code on PHP and JS.

I took all user data (sub, base_uri, account_id ) with that documentation https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/config-and-auth at my site using cURL

Now I need send pdf file for that I generate at my site with that access for user sign like I have understood I need that https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app  and Envelopes: create https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create#examples

I send POST request to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes  with accountId=account_id  from user data, also I send json with user data and doc data in base64 in, but there is nothing, so I don't understand:

1. How should I call "create" method with POST to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes ?
2. What Id should I use in {accountId}?
3. At what format should I send the document for the sign?
4. Where can I find that doc after create?

Can you show me code example or show documentation with normal examples of POST request for that method.

Comment: I don't knnow the answer right away - but you could compare with their postman request collection here: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman/ - it worked like charm when I tried...

Comment: Please EDIT your question to include exactly what was returned by DocuSign when you did the POST to create the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a demo environment, I believe your authentication url is `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information`. For production accounts, since the subdomain can be different you can find the correct baseUrl using a GET request to `https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?api_password=true` using Postman. This gives you the right baseUrl as well as your authentication information.

Here is how you can create a template using a base64 which is a `POST` call to `{{baseUrl}}/templates`

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<insert encoded base64 here",
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "blank1.pdf"
    }
  ],
  "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {}
}
```

Also, if you need to generate more requests make sure you check out the Postman collection that contains different examples as Sebastian mentioned too:

[DocuSign Postman Collection](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman/)

Comment: Hi @Payf1 Your answer is not correct if OAuth authentication is used. If OAuth authentication is used, learn the user's accountId and base path from API call [OAuth::UserInfo](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints)

Comment: Yes. This works if you are using a legacy header authentication